# Weird behavior with UILabel and Text propert

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uilabel

Im trying to do something that I think is super simple.

i have 3 integers - prevgues1 , 2 and 3

and i have 3 UILabels prevguess1, 2 and 3

the ints have 1 less s.

When I set the text of the label so

```
prevguess1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", prevguess1]
prevguess2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", prevguess2];
prevguess3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", prevguess3];
```

the label just set to a number like 89324 or something like that.

I just don't know what my problem is.

Any ideas would be helpful

Cheers

Sam

Note:

I have tried setting the text simply to a string - and have had luck. 
but when i set it to a integer, which start as 0 value, (in viewdidload) the weirdness happens

Comment: If prevguess1 is unsigned, you should use @"%u" as the format. And did you check real values of those integers in debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
prevguess1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", prevguess1];
```

Here you treat `prevguess1` as a label and as an integer - probably there's a typo somewhere?

Even if it's not a matter of your problems I think you should consider changing the way you name your variables a bit to avoid possible confusion.